# jQuery understanding `wrap`

Tags: jquery

I'm having some syntax understanding issues.

I'm trying to take a div, clone it, wrap the clone in two new generated divs, and then stick it all into the DOM right before the closing BODY tag. This is what I have:

```
$('.myDiv').click(function(){
    var $myDiv = $(this).clone();

    var $myWrapper1 = $('div').css('border','10px solid blue');
    var $myWrapper2 = $('div').css('border','10px solid green');

    $myDiv.wrap($myWrapper1).wrap($myWrapper2).appendTo('body');
});
```

jsbin live example: http://jsbin.com/upedox/4/

This isn't doing what I am expecting it to do, so clearly I'm not fully understanding `wrap`. What I want to happen is to end up with a copy of my div (red border) with two divs wrapping it (one with a green and blue border) and for that to then be inserted after the existing div.

What is instead happening is that the div gets cloned, but isn't wrapped with the other divs but, rather, it's content is just inserted into the last div I wrap it with (so I end up with a cloned green border div) and it sticks it above the existing div.

What am I misunderstanding with wrap?

Comment: Remember that `.wrap()` is still returning the original selection and not the selection wrapped. Basically, your second call is negating your first call. (or so I my understanding).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I explained, picture the following:

```
<div class="foo">Bar</div>
```

If you want to wrap foo in a bar div, you'd call it:

```
var $r = $('.foo').wrap($('<div>',{class:'bar'}));
```

Instead of $r resulting in `<div class="bar"><div class="foo">Bar</div></div>` (as you're expecting) what you're actually getting back is the original `<div class="foo">Bar</div>` (and inside the DOM it's been wrapped with `<div class="bar"></div>`).

So, instead (considering you're cloning it and not working directly in DOM) use `append` instead:

```
var $orig = $('.foo').clone();

var $firstWrap = $('<div>',{class:'bar'});
var $secondWrap = $('<div>',{class:'baz'});

var $r = $secondWrap.append($firstWrap.append($orig));
```

Now, the above has `<div class="baz"><div class="bar"><div class="foo">Bar</div></div></div>` inside (like you're desiring) which you can then `appendTo('body')`

[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aurBj/)

Comment: Ah! It makes sense now. I was thinking of wrap behaving like append, where you can chain to create a nested object. But I guess it just doesn't work that way. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm...actually, that syntax doesn't work. I'm getting an error with the nested appends: http://jsbin.com/upedox/6

Comment: @DA: the problem is how you (expect to) create new DIV wrapping elements. The way you have it, you're telling jQuery to "find div, then apply the border style to it." You want `$myWrapper1 = $('<div>').css(...)` (which tells jQuery to create a new div with the border style applied to it.) _[note the use of the markup tags in the jQuery selector argument]_ -- `$('div')` = select `<div>`, `$('<div>')` = create new `<div>`

Comment: Brad: I'm an idiot. I was coding while sleep deprived and now slapping my forehead at missing that obvious one. ;)

Answer (score 1):

`$($myDiv).wrap($myWrapper1)` returns `$myDiv` which doesn't include the wrapped element.

The code should look like below.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('.myDiv').click(function(){
        var $myDiv = $(this).clone();

        var $myWrapper1 = $('<div>').css('border','10px solid blue');
        var $myWrapper2 = $('<div>').css('border','10px solid green');
        $myDiv.wrap($myWrapper1).parent()
            .wrap($myWrapper2).parent()
            .appendTo('body');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks mmhan...I like this option too. It goes more along with my original chain of thought.